# Android VideoView playback issues on recorded files

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

The problem I have is trying to get my program to playback a .amr file that has been recorded using the default android voice recorder. I have also downloaded a mp3 voice recorder and tried playback on that but it doesn't work either. I have downloaded .amr and .mp3 files which work perfectly it's just the ones that are recorded that don't seem to work.

code dump:

```
private static final String recording = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()) + File.separatorChar + "My Documents" + File.separatorChar + "My Recordings";
    ArrayList<String> songList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ListView playList;
    private VideoView videoView;
    private MediaController mediaController;

private void loadPlayList()
    {
        songList.clear();

        File home = new File(recording);
        if (home.listFiles( new AmrFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new AmrFilter())) {
                songList.add(file.getName());
            }
        }

        if (home.listFiles( new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())) {
                songList.add(file.getName());
            }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, songList);
        playList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

class AmrFilter implements FilenameFilter {

        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return (name.endsWith(".amr")); 
        }       
    }

    private void refreshPlayList()
    {
        songList.clear();

        File home = new File(SD_PATH);
        if (home.listFiles( new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())) {
                songList.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, songList);
        playList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

private void playFile(String currentFile) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException {
        videoView.setVideoPath(currentFile);
        videoView.start();
        playBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Set the progress max
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                playBar.setMax(videoView.getDuration());
                startSeekbar.setMax(videoView.getDuration());
                startSeekbar.setProgress(videoView.getCurrentPosition());
                stopSeekbar.setMax(videoView.getDuration());
                stopSeekbar.setProgress(videoView.getDuration());
                int msec = videoView.getDuration();
                int time[] = secondsToMinutes(msec);
                totalPlayTime.setText(time[0] + ":" + time[1] + ":" + time[2]);
            }
        });

        handler.postDelayed(runner, 1000);
    }
```

The logcat error is:

```
07-01 05:51:45.363: E/MediaPlayer(2912): error (1, -2147483648)
07-01 05:51:45.383: E/MediaPlayer(2912): Error (1,-2147483648)
07-01 05:51:45.383: D/VideoView(2912): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

I'm not sure what the problem is but its restricted to the ones that I record. I don't think it's file permissions as the Android mp3 player can play the mp3 recording.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.jahed.medialooper.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

playing sound file in video view not a great idea.
VideoView is to play the video files you can play .mp4 .3gp with ease

try using the MediaPlayer

Comment: Thank you for the prompt feedback, however my program supports video files and can play .mp4 files and show the video. For this reason I can't switch to a Media Player. I initially started with a MediaPlayer but changed as a VideoView was better suited to my needs.